# Cannot find javascript file node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I linked my javascript file in one of my HTML pages but I keep getting the error `http://localhost:3000/users/javascript/users-edit.js`.

Here is my application structure:

`app/public/javascript/users-edit.js`

`app/views/users-edit.handlebars`

In my app.js file I have:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

In my users-edit.handlebars file, I clearly link in my .js file:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/users-edit.js"></script>`

Note - I have several other handlebars files where I link the .js file in the exact same manner, but they all work.

Can someone help?

Comment: Does `/javascript/users-edit.js` work?

Comment: that works!! - do you know why the other pages worked without the preceding `/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for `/users/javascript/users-edit.js` but the file is in `/javascript/users-edit.js`

Presumably when you said `src="javascript/users-edit.js"` you forgot to take into account the URL of the page including that HTML might not be in the root of the site, and you should have said `src="/javascript/users-edit.js"` (explicitly starting the URL resolution from the root instead of the current directory).